# Silverlight will not load

Tags: .net, silverlight

I am trying to create a "Hello world" application in Silverlight 3.0, but when it runs, there is an error: (IE 8)

Error:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application  
Code: 2104    
Category: InitializeError       
Message: Could not download the Silverlight application. Check web server settings
```

When the project was created I chose to host the Silverlight application in a new web site (ASP.net web application project )

Here is my code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World!"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I also have tried to run in Firefox, it does not work there either.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not hosting it in a new ASP.NET application project, the error did not show.

Answer (score 3):

The MIME types on your webserver are not setup correctly to host your silver light application. The MIME types needed are:

```
.xaml    application/xaml+xml 
 .xap    application/x-silverlight-app 
 .xbap    application/x-ms-xbap
```

Comment: How can I add the MIME types to the ASP.NET development server running from VS 2008?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same exception and I had the MIME types added correctly.  My mistake (a very obvious one) was that I had "allow anonymous access" but I forgot to give the Internet Guest Account (the one that is impersonating for anonymous access) permission to access my applications virtual folder in IIS.  So, I just wanted to share my solution, just in case it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I just have got this problem. Solved it by instaling MIME Types.

Answer (score 0):

Check url of your SL application file. Looks like its unable to download it.